# tableView reloadData doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

For some reason, [self.tableView reloadData]; just wont work.
In my .h file I have:

```
@interface SearchOptions : UIViewController <UINavigationBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> 
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
     .....
}
```

I've tried:

[self.tableView reloadData];

and

[self.myTableView reloadData];

Any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you’ve correctly bound your outlet in Interface Builder (check myTableView is not nil). If that’s not it, are you getting the initial data in your table view? If not, then it probably means you haven’t set your SearchOptions instance as the data source for your table—check this in Interface Builder and stick some break points on the data source methods.

Comment: I've set:   myTableView.delegate = self; and myTableView.dataSource = self;     ...nothing.  The outlets and class are set in IB as well. The table displays just fine in a grouped style (set in IB). It's always the little unexpected problems that get you!

Comment: Should I be allocating or initializing myTableView somehow?

Comment: If I add  myTableView.dataSource = nil;  the table is blank. So I guess it isn't nil.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's non-`nil`? That is, that your outlet is properly connected?

Is the property `tableView` synthesized to the ivar `myTableView`? (You don't include that code in your question.)

Comment: How would you synthesize the tableView property to the ivar myTableView?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you mean:   @property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *myTableView;

Comment: In @Implementation file (.m)

@synthesize myTableView;

Comment: You don't need to synthesize it, so that won’t be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it! The problem was that because of other reasons, I wasn't able to reuse my cells and this was my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *kCustomCellID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyCellID%d", indexPath];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCustomCellID] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    if (selectOrDeselectInteger == 1) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
    }
    if (selectOrDeselectInteger == 2) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

I just had to add this afterwards:

```
    if (cell != nil) 
{
    if (selectOrDeselectInteger == 1) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
    }
    if (selectOrDeselectInteger == 2) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;          
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone for the help. Sorry this code wasn't in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your outlet isn't connected in IB.

Comment: Actually, it is connected. But it's acting like it isn't.